# How to integrate caffe in KurentoMediaServer

Tags: opencv, caffe, kurento

**What I do**:

1.I installed the opencv-plugin-sample in the kurenoMediaPlayer(from the link https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample) and run a sample opencv face detection.

**What i have to do:**

1.Now i need to integrate **caffe**(http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html) into KMS ,so I can able to run more complex opencv algorithms in KMS.

**What I need to know:**

1.Is there any specific way to integrate caffe in KurentoMediaServer?

Comment: Have you tried something? I don't know how caffe works, but maybe if you provide some information about what you try. This way there will be more chances of someone helping you. Probably it is like a library, try linking it modifiying CMakeList

Comment: @santoscadenas Thanks for the reply,Our aim to confirm the possiblity of integrating caffe with KMS.Not tried yet .Now we have linked a sample library(.so) with KMS(by modifying the CmakeList),next we will try linking Caffe and let  you know about the updates